# getJSON on a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, getjson, ofbiz

So I have a JSON file which contains some data, I've been trying to send a request from a JavaScript file using `$.getJSON` to retrieve that file but I'm unsure how to do so, is it possible to send a request directly to that file without having to setup `request-map` or `view-map`? If so where would store the file to make it publicly available.

I've tried using `<@ofbisContentUrl>` as it is stored in `/images/[...]`:

```
$.getJSON(
    '<@ofbizContentUrl>/images/[...]</@ofbizContentUrl>',
    function (data, text_status, jqXHR) {
        map.load_layer_data(data, [layer_file, layer_type]);
    }
).error(function (jqXHR, text_status, error_thrown) {
    busy.unset();

    /** Error reporting later... **/
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
        message: 'Failed to data for layer data.'
    });
});
```

This failed, so I then tried to setup a `request-map`/`view-map` but the again had no success,

```
<request-map uri="frs_get_mapping_points">
    <security https="false" auth="false"/>
    <response name="success" type="request" value="frs_json"></response>
</request-map>
```

The documentation lacks any suitable information  in regards to making a simple AJAX request to a local file hence I'm completely stuck. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JavaScript request was not parsing the Freemarker expression `<@ofbisContentUrl>` as a result it was not finding the file. What I had to do was in my `.ftl` file create a dummy variable with the location stores using `<@ofbisContentUrl>` and manipulate the string using `.replace()` to point it to the correct location.